# Qlabel settext is crashing

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog, qlabel

I have created a dialog box using the qt designer. it generate me a .ui, cpp and header.

the cpp is defined :

```
DialogAbout::DialogAbout(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::DialogAbout)
{
    ui->buildversion->setText("toto");
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

header

```
class DialogAbout : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit DialogAbout(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~DialogAbout();
    QLabel *buildversion;

private:
    Ui::DialogAbout *ui;
};
```

and the UI looks like :

[image]

My app is crashing each time I'm accessing the this dialog box when trying to

```
ui->buildversion->setText("toto");
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: attach a debugger to find out what is causing the crash exactly.

Comment: Maybe calling ui->setupUi(this) before setting the label text would be better idea?

Comment: @vahancho thanks it was so simple that I have run through all complexe solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should `setupUi` before:

```
DialogAbout::DialogAbout(QWidget *parent) :
   QDialog(parent),
   ui(new Ui::DialogAbout)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->buildversion->setText("toto");
}
```

Once `setupUi()` function has been called, it becomes possible to modify the user interface as needed.

You can learn more about using a designer UI file in your application from [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html).